# Rendering React/Redux app multiple times on a single page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've been working on a React/Redux application for building a quote.  A gross simplification of my state would look something like this:

```
{
  account: { name: 'john doe' },
  lineItems:[
    { product: {id: 123, ...}, price: 10, units: 5 },
    { product: {id: 124, ...}, price: 10, units: 5 },
  ],
  modifiers: { couponCode: 'asdf', vip: true }  
}
```

and my reducers would be sliced something like this:

```
const appReducer = combineReducers<GlobalState>({
  account: accountReducer,
  lineItems: lineItemReducer,
  modifiers: modifersReducer,
});
```

I've just recently gotten a requirements where I would essentially need to be able to render the entire app multiple times on a single page (basically show 1 or more quotes for different accounts on a single page).  So a single state would now need to look something like this:

```
{
  quotes: {
    "0": {
      account: { name: 'john doe' },
      lineItems:[
        { product: {id: 123, ...}, price: 10, units: 5 },
        { product: {id: 124, ...}, price: 10, units: 5 },
      ],
      modifiers: { couponCode: 'asdf', vip: true }  
    },
    "1": {
      account: { name: 'billy jean' },
      lineItems:[
        { product: {id: 123, ...}, price: 10, units: 5 },
      ],
      modifiers: { couponCode: '', vip: false }  
    },
  }
}
```

But obviously this new state shape doesn't really work with how I've sliced my reducers.  Also, seems like I'd have to refactor all my actions so that I know which quote they should be operating on?  For example, if I had an action like this:

```
{
  type: 'UPDATE_PRICE'
  payload: { productId: 123, newPrice: 15 }
}
```

Seems like the product `123` on both quotes would be updated.

Maybe there is instead some way I can just render the entire app on the page without having to refactor my entire state?  I'm not sure what my best approach would be that wouldn't requirement me to rewrite large portions of the app.

Comment: Why not writing another reducer that uses `appReducer` to handle the entire new state?

Comment: @norbertpy not sure I follow,  Could you provide a brief example of what that might look like as and answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the idea. It's basically using one reducer inside another one. As simple as using a function within another function body. You can run it on [runkit.com](https://runkit.com/5a43cc782cef4c00139321a5/5a63a706816c7c00127c8099) as well.

```
const { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';

const UPDATE_ACCOUNT = 'app/updat-account';
const ADD_QUOTE = 'quote/add-quote';

const appActions = {
  updateAcount: (q_id, a) => ({ type: UPDATE_ACCOUNT, payload: { q_id, name: a }}),
};

const quoteActions = {
  addQuote: q_id => ({ type: ADD_QUOTE, payload: q_id }),
};


const accountReducer = (app = {}, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  switch (type) {
    case UPDATE_ACCOUNT:
      return { ...app, name: payload.name }
    default:
      return app;
  }  
};

const appReducer = combineReducers({
  account: accountReducer,
  lineItems: (app ={}, action) => app, // just a placeholder
  modifiers: (app ={}, action) => app, // just a placeholder
});

const quoteReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  switch (type) {
    case ADD_QUOTE:
      return { ...state, [payload]: {} };
    case UPDATE_ACCOUNT: {
      const app = state[payload.q_id];
      return app
        ? { ...state, [payload.q_id]: appReducer(state[payload.q_id], action) }
        : state;
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}


const store = createStore(quoteReducer);

store.dispatch(quoteActions.addQuote(3));
store.dispatch(quoteActions.addQuote(2));

store.dispatch(appActions.updateAcount(3, 'apple'));
store.dispatch(appActions.updateAcount(4, 'orange')); // non-existent quote

store.getState():

/**
{
  "2": {},
  "3": {
    "account": {
      "name": "apple"
    },
    "lineItems": {},
    "modifiers": {}
  }
}
*/
```

Comment: This is helpful.  The big thing I'd like to point out is that I had to add a parameters to all my actions so they know which quote state to operate on

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add my specific answer here..

Basically I added a new root reducer as norbertpy suggested.  However, I also had to add a parameter `quoteId` to each action to specify which quote the action originated from and should operate on.  This was the most time consuming part of the refactor as now each component that dispatches actions must have access to the quote key.

**Reducer**

```
const quoteReducer = combineReducers({
  account: accountReducer,
  lineItems: lineItemReducer,
  modifiers: modifersReducer,
});

const rootReducer = (state = {quotes: []}, action) => {
  const newQuoteState = quoteReducer(state.quotes[action.quoteId], action);
  const newQuotes = {...state.quotes};
  newQuotes[action.quoteId] = newQuoteState;
  return {...state, ...{quotes: newQuotes}};
};
```

**Action**

```
{
  type: 'UPDATE_PRICE'
  quoteId: '0',
  payload: { productId: 123, newPrice: 15 }
}
```